# Syntax error trying to write SQL procedure

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a table called "instructors" that has columns "name", "dept_name", "salary"

I'm trying to create a procedure that takes a department name (dept_name) for IN and returns the highest and lowest salaries in that department as two OUTs.

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure min_max(in dept_name_ varchar(20), 
                         out max_salary numeric(12,2),
                         out min_salary numeric(12,2))
BEGIN
    select max(salary) into max_salary,
    from instructor 
    where instructor.dept_name = min_max.dept_name_;

    select min(salary) into min_salary,
    from instructor
    where instructor.dept_name = min_max.dept_name_;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from instructor 
    where instructor.dept_name = min_max.dept_name_;

  ' at line 6
```

I've gone through the procedure a couple times, I cannot figure out what might be causing the error.

Comment: In SQL `SELECT` statements, don't put a comma after the last column in the select-list before the `FROM`.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I usually write my queries on one line; going to two lines made me think there needed to be a comma there.